# How to share single Filter instance between several ServletContextHandler's

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, embedded-jetty

In my code I am using a filter class from a 3rd party jar that can be instantiated once.
When I create my embedded jetty server instance, I have several ServletContextHandler and for each one of them I added above the filter.
Is there a way to share the instance filter between 2 or more context handlers?

See the code below:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            Server jettyServer = new Server(8080);

            final HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();

            ServletContextHandler restCtx = initRestCtx();

            ServletContextHandler wsCtx = initWsCtx();

            handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{
                    restCtx,
                    wsCtx,
                    new DefaultHandler()});

            jettyServer.setHandler(handlers);
            jettyServer.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(String.format("An issue occur when starting server: %s",e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    private static ServletContextHandler initWsCtx() {
        ServletContextHandler wsCtx = createSessionBasedContextHandler();
        wsCtx.setContextPath("/ws");
        wsCtx.addFilter(new MyFilter(), "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
        return wsCtx;
    }

    private static ServletContextHandler initRestCtx() {
        ServletContextHandler restCtx = createSessionBasedContextHandler();
        restCtx.setContextPath("/rest");
        restCtx.addFilter(new MyFilter(), "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
        return restCtx;
    }

    private static ServletContextHandler createSessionBasedContextHandler() {
        ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        servletContextHandler
                .getSessionHandler()
                .setMaxInactiveInterval(30);

        return servletContextHandler;
    }
```

I have simplified the code here so I must have 2 different contexts and I can not make it to be one context.

Comment: Does the Filter use or store a reference to the `javax.servlet.ServletContext` during initialization?

Comment: Explain why you cannot have just 1 `ServletContextHandler`?  so far, from your example it looks quite possible to have just 1.

Comment: The filter does not use or store a reference of the ServletContext. How can I do it? How can it help?

Comment: Each ServletContextHandler instance need to be initialized differently, some of them is initialized with ServletContextHandler.NO_SESSIONS other with ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS. Moreover I have contexts that have preAuthFilters and EventListener that other contexts don't have.